# Entity Framework, deleting from a collection results in foreign key exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a code-first EF database solution. The following are my model classes:

```
public class HolidayAllowance
{
    private decimal _taken;

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public decimal Allowance { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Holiday>  Holidays { get; set; }

    public decimal Taken
    {
        get { return Holidays?.Sum(x => x.Duration) ?? 0; }
        set { _taken = value; }
    }

    public decimal Remaining => Allowance - Taken;
}

public class Holiday
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime HolidayStartDay { get; set; }
    public HolidayType HolidayStartDayType { get; set; }
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }
    public int HolidayAllowanceId { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```
public class StaffAndInvoiceManagerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HolidayAllowance> HolidayAllowances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Termination> Terminations { get; set; }
}
```

The method from my `DataService` that tries to delete a holiday from the `holidayAllowance`:

```
public void DeleteHoliday(Holiday selectedHoliday)
{
   var allowance = _dbContext
       .HolidayAllowances
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == selectedHoliday.HolidayAllowanceId);

    allowance?
      .Holidays
      .Remove(selectedHoliday);

   _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The method on my ViewModel that calls that:

```
private void DeleteHoliday()
{
    if (!_messageBoxService.AskYesNoQuestion("Delete Holiday?", "Do you want to delete this holiday?")) return;

    _staffDataService.DeleteHoliday(SelectedHoliday);
    HolidayAllowance.Holidays.Remove(SelectedHoliday);
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(HolidayAllowance));
}
```

The problem is, when I try to delete a `Holiday` from the `HolidayAllowance.Holidays` collection I get the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I don't understand why that would be a FK violation? I'm just trying to delete from a collection.

My DB tables that EF is generating.

[image]

I can execute the following SQL and it works without throwing a FK exception.

```
delete from dbo.Holidays
where Id = 2
```

The Foreign Key its generating looks like this, If I script to Create in SSMS

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Holidays]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Holidays_dbo.HolidayAllowances_HolidayAllowanceId] 
FOREIGN KEY([HolidayAllowanceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[HolidayAllowances] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Holidays] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Holidays_dbo.HolidayAllowances_HolidayAllowanceId]
GO
```

I've tried the following in my DBContext after reading @Fals comment below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I would have thought EF was doing similar ? Still no luck.

Comment: Check out if Cascade is enabled. It's probably trying to delete also other dependencies together.

Comment: @Fals, I've updated the question. I added Remove Cascade Delete conventions and still the error persists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix for this, but I'm not sure why it works or if it's the correct way to do it. Anyway,

```
_dbContext.Entry(selectedHoliday).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And the item is deleted. I have no idea why I have to do this and not just delete it from it's parent, but it works.